# FFMpeg permission denied error

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ffmpeg

I installed ffmpeg into /root/bin

I followed this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

I now want a non admin to access it. I created a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin

now if i try to execute i get:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spend weeks to remove some conflicts of libraries and ffmpeg got installed. But unfortunately I installed it in `/root/bin/`.

Typing this in the terminal fixed it for me:

```
cp -r /root/ffmpeg_build 

cp -r /root/bin/{ffmpeg,ffplay,ffserver,x264,yasm} /usr/local/bin/
```

And it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a link whose target is in a directory you don't have access to. The effective permissions on a link are those of its target.

I have no idea why you decided to install in `/root/bin`, that is not what the guide you followed tells you to do. You should have installed everything in `$HOME/bin`, *your* `$HOME`. I am guessing that you followed all the steps from the guide but running everything from a root shell (`sudo -i` or `sudo su` or `su`). If so, you *should* be able to get everything to work as expected if you just copy the directories created to your `$HOME`:

```
sudo cp -r /root/ffmpeg_build ~/
sudo cp /root/bin/* ~/bin
```

The last command will copy everything from `/root/bin` to `~/bin` which might not be what you want. If for whatever reason you have other files in there, just pick up the ones you created for `ffmpeg`:

```
sudo cp /root/bin/{ffmpeg,ffplay,ffserver,x264,yasm} ~/bin/
```

Anyway, once all files have been copied, you can create the link in `/usr/local/bin` for non-admin users. Even better, you can just move the directories above to `/usr/local` and the binaries directly to `~/usr/local/bin`. However, note that they will be overwritten if you ever install `ffmpeg` from the repositories using `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`.